# How to get update history of application installed on the Android platform

Tags: android

I want to know, is there a way for the end user to know through UI, following information for any application installed on the Android platform:

1. App installed date
2. App Version
3. Installed date of the update of the App
4. App Version for the Update of the app

Thanks and Regards,
Venkat

Answer (score 0):

1. Through UI, the installed date cannot be known.
2. Yes, it is visible if the user navigates from `Home -> Settings -> Applications -> Manage Applications -> Application Name` from below image
   [image]
3. The updated date of the App cannot be known
4. The Version can be known as Point 2.

Comment: So, that means there is no way for the end user to track the update history for any android application installed

Comment: Yes. But there is a possibility to track if your application data/updated_data is not stored in Private Application Context.

Answer (score -1):

You can follow these steps:

1) open the google play store
2) view your apps in the google play store (sorry this one steps not too specific)
3) click on the "installed" tab so it shows your installed apps
4) click the filter button and select to sort them by date of last update!! :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

You wrote, "sorry this one steps not too specific".

After opening the Google Play Store app, I found "My apps & games" by clicking on the round icon in the upper left corner of the Play Store app window.  "My apps & games" was the first item in the pop-up list.

I hope this helps others trudging along in my footsteps.

And by the way, very frustrating that it is not possible to display a history showing when each app was updated and whether that update was manual (initiated by the user) or automatic!

Comment: Sorry, I meant "upper **right** corner of the Play Store app window", **not** "upper **left** corner of the Play Store app window"!  I am running Android Version 10 with One UI Core 2.5 and Google Play Store Version 25.5.22-21 on a recently-acquired Galaxy A12.

Comment: Please see https://www.wikihow.com/Update-Apps-on-Android for step-by-step instructions with screenshots.

Comment: If the app was installed via play store, when you view the list of installed apps, it offers a sort option for 'last updated' as well. This was a good answer so long as it was from the play store.